# Transform object key values using map and string template literals

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. I need to transform data using the map higher-order function. I should use a prop function helper for transforming. The prop function takes a string as a parameter. How can I pass an appropriate callback into map using string template literals:

```
let data = [
  {
    age: 25,
    name: 'Michael'
  },
  {
    age: 20,
    name: 'David'
  }
]

let name = data.map(`${prop('name')}`).join(',')  
let age = data.map(`${prop('age')}`).join(',') // 25, 20

function prop(string) {
  return value[string]
}

console.log(name) //Michael, David
console.log(age) // 25, 20
```

Comment: How is `prop()` getting `value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `prop` function to accept both `key` and `obj`. Now you can pass it to the `Array.map()` function after calling it with the `key`.

```js
const data = [{"age":25,"name":"Michael"},{"age":20,"name":"David"}]

const prop = key => obj => obj[key] // or String(obj[key]) if you want the value to always be a string

const name = data.map(prop('name')).join(',')
const age = data.map(prop('age')).join(',')

console.log(name) //Michael, David
console.log(age) // 25, 20
```